# How to write directly druid from Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, druid

I want to write the data in flink to druid.
I know the tranquility which enables above scenario however I cannot find the working project written in Java.

If someone achieve the above scenario, I really appreciate it if you could guide me how to resolve my issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **Apache Flink and Druid** are running in **local**.
All you need to do is **enable Tranquility server** for Druid as defined in the link https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-tranquility.html

If your tranquility server configurations for Druid are set correctly. The following **Spring Boot Java Code** with **Flink** should allow you to push data into **Druid** using **Http Post** method.

> **FlinkDruidApp.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FlinkDruidApp {


    private static String url = "http://localhost:8200/v1/post/wikipedia";

    private static RestTemplate template;

    private static HttpHeaders headers;


    FlinkDruidApp() {

        template = new RestTemplate();
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(FlinkDruidApp.class, args);

        // Creating Flink Execution Environment
        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        //Define data source
        DataSet<String> data = env.readTextFile("/wikiticker-2015-09-12-sampled.json");

        // Trasformation on the data 
        data.map(x -> {

            return httpsPost(x).toString();
        }).print();


    }

    // http post method to post data in Druid
    private static ResponseEntity<String> httpsPost(String json) {

        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity =
                new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response =
                template.exchange("http://localhost:8200/v1/post/wikipedia", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                        String.class);

        return response;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    } 

}
```

> **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.flinkdruid</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlinkDruid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FlinkDruid</name>
    <description>Flink Druid Connection</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> **Output on console**

```
<200,{"result":{"received":1,"sent":1}},[Date:"Mon, 23 Sep 2019 13:29:39 GMT", Content-Type:"application/json; charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"34", Server:"Jetty(9.2.5.v20141112)"]>
```

Comment: is it possible to write streaming data consumed by Springboot from pulsar topic and write to Druid DB?